# Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to the codeigniter programming. When I am trying to connect with the database and retrieve data from the table, I Found Error like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$result
Filename: models/haii.php
Line Number: 15.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: views/getquery.php
Line Number: 2
```

I am using this code to connect with the database using codeigniter:

## Controller:

```
<?php
class product extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    function getall()
    {
        $this->load->model('haii');
        $data['query']=$this->haii->you();
        $this->load->view('getquery',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

## Model:

```
<?php
class haii extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function you()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('member');
        return $query->result;
    }
}
?>
```

## View:

```
<?php
foreach($query as $row)
{
    print $row->username;
    print $row->password;
    print $row->fname;
    print $row->lname;
    print $row->contact;
    print "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: use result() with an open close `()` you are calling a funciton not a variable, on you're model, on function i mean method, on variable i mean object

Comment: @tomexsans:Thank you very much.It Working!!

Answer (score 8):

Use `return $query->result();` instead of `return $query->result;` in your `you()` function.
`result` is a method, not a class member.

Comment: yes `result()` is a function which contains standard object, or you can return it as an array `return $query->result_array();`

Answer (score 1):

Change your Model function

```
function you()
{
    $query=$this->db->get('member');
    return $query->result;
}
```

To

**`return $query->result();`**

It will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe can fix it

```
<?php
class haii extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function you()
    {
        $query=$this->db->get('member');
        return $query;
    }
}
?>
```

in views

```
<?php
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    print $row->username;
    print $row->password;
    print $row->fname;
    print $row->lname;
    print $row->contact;
    print "<br>";
}
?>
```